# How can I determine if /tmp is a mounted NFS share?

Tags: unix, solaris

How can I determine if `/tmp` is a mounted NFS share on Solaris?

The issue at hand stems from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365476/what-mistake-am-i-making-if-even-root-cannot-delete-a-lock-file-created-using-o), where Jonathan Leffler commented that

> ...
>   If your /tmp file system is NFS mounted (unlikely, but not impossible), then root has few privileges on that file system.

Comment: What's the *real* problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Somebody pointed out that root user id might have limited permission inside /tmp folder when /tmp folder is mounted on NFS and in my case i was not able to delete some files from /tmp folder even by root user id . So i wanted to check that

Comment: You're going to have to explain a little deeper than that.

Comment: Not all NFS have that problem, only those with root squash enabled have that.

Answer (score 3):

On both Solaris  and Linux, this will show the file system used by /tmp:

```
mount | grep /tmp
```

/tmp might not be a mount point but just a subdirectory in /, you can figure it out with:

```
df -k /tmp
```

In this latter case, to know the root file system, use

```
mount | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris and Linux do:

```
mount -v | grep nfs | grep tmp
```

If your /tmp actually is mounted on NFS it will show up in the output.

Answer (score -1):

I think

```
findmnt -t nfs /tmp
```

would do this.

Comment: On which Solaris?

Comment: I can't see where this is stated in the question. This however works here on my centos 6 machine. no reason to rate down. this answer is not wrong.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:solaris]

Comment: Its also tagged linux. ;) How should i know which one is relevant when its not stated in the question? however lets leave it as that.

Comment: Assume both are.

Comment: @l1zard, If you are answering for only one OS, please state that in your answer.  Also, please test that the syntax is correct before posting it.  If you cannot test it at that moment, please follow up once you are able to.